# Use PHP to search for or insert data into a remote mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have an html based application that allows users to store and search information in a mysql database.  They run this on their own servers, so it isn't centralized.  I'd like to add a function that allows them to see if their information corresponds to any known info in a central database, and if it isn't, they would have the option to add it to the central db.  I'm not sure if the triggering script would be best placed on the client, or server side, so I'm at a loss as to where to start with this.  Any script or config suggestions would be welcome.

Edit to add:
The data is preformatted, not created by the user.  It consists of 7-10 fields of data that will likely be consistent with that seen by other users.  The purpose is to build a troubleshooting database for users to reference or add to.  The central server will be based on Q2A to allow upvotes, comments, etc.

Comment: Take a look at MySQL Federated storage engine, it allows you to make a remote database appear to be on a local server.

Comment: That looks like a nice tool, but I'll be working with thousands of clients, so it wouldn't be practical to add more overhead on their end.

Comment: How are your users accessing the database? I know it is through PHP but do you use an ORM? Do you use REST?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the opposite of what [Freebase](http://www.freebase.com/) does. In Freebase, users can connect to the Freebase API and check to see if something exists in the Freebase API if it does not already exist in their database. It is then up to them to cache the entry for faster retrieval in the future. Alternatively, at least in the past, the Freebase community enabled writing to the Freebase database using the MQL API.

If you are suggesting would strike me as being very involved. If you have content creators you really trust, you maybe can get away with not having any review process, but otherwise you will need some peer review and perhaps some programming. Unless you have no content standards, and it is anything goes, your database could quickly become overloaded with nonsense or things you don't want your website to be associated with (whatever those somethings might be).

Without knowing more about your database, I can't really say what those things would be, but what I will say is that if you are looking to have people throw stuff into a centralized location, you may want to (a) use something like OAuth, (b) set up some balances, because while one of your clients may think it's very important to have the 100 reasons why liberals/conservatives suck", another one of your clients may take offense. Guess who they will blame?

That being said, creating a RESTful API (don't know if you already have one or not) with a flag for `insert_if_not_exists` could work.

i.e. `api.php?{json_string}` would be picked up by a function/functions which determined what the user wanted to do in the json_string.

On the backend, your PHP function could parse it to an array very easily and if the `insert_if_not_exists` flag is triggered, you can create the post while you pull the data. Otherwise you just pull the data (or leave that part out if you only want to give them the option to post and not to pull in this fashion).